# Compile failed when using boost thread

Tags: c++, boost

this is my code:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost; 
void task1()
{std::cout << "This is task1!" << std::endl;}
void task2()
{std::cout << "This is task2!" << std::endl;}
int main () 
{
    thread thread_1 = thread(task1);
    thread thread_2 = thread(task2);
    thread_2.join();
    thread_1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile with:

```
 g++ test.cc -o test -lboost_thread -lpthread -lboost_system
```

compile failed:

```
/tmp/ccN9cPiI.o: In function `boost::system::generic_category()':test.cc(.text._ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv[_ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv]+0x7):
undefined reference to `boost::system::detail::generic_category_instance'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's wrong with that?
My system is Ubuntu 18.04,boost is 1_68.0.

Comment: Why use `boost::thread` and not `std::thread`? Can't you use C++11/14/17?

Comment: Well,I just want to test my boost is installed correctly.so I try to make smoe code to test.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your example and it works. I tried with boost_1_66_0 and boost_1_65_1 on Ubuntu.

The actual problem is boost itself, not your installation. You can check open bug here:

https://github.com/boostorg/system/issues/24

Comment: Great.It's very helpful to me.